# in_array is not working even though i see a match

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if there is a duplicate value in a foreach loop.

Here's my attempt which ain't working:

```
$popup_array = array();
foreach($xml->config->popup as $popup_item)
    {
    $duplicate_test = $popup_item->attributes()->name; 
    if (in_array_r($duplicate_test, $popup_array)){
        echo "match found for " . $duplicate_test;
    }

    echo "item: " . $duplicate_test . "<br />";

    $popup_array[$i] = $duplicate_test;
$i++;   
    }
```

Now i can clearly see there is 2 duplicates, here is what i see at end when i print_r as you can see 2 x default and 2 x lost and the echo also shows default and lost so the in_array is not working and im not sure why:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => Default
    )

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => Default
    )

[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => pipe
    )

[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => raised
    )

[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => steal
    )

[5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => lost
    )

[6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => lost
    )

[7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => teach
    )

[8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => terrain
    )
```

Is there an error in my code? Is it something to do with the simpleXMLEelement and thats turned it into a multidimensional array and i need to search a different way. If i loop through the array and do this:

```
$popup_length = count($popup_array);
for($x=0;$x<$popup_length;$x++)
{
echo $popup_array[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
```

It returns:

```
Default
Default
pipe
raised
steal
lost
lost
teach
terrain
```

Comment: What's _inside_ `in_array_r`? (if it was not defined, it would emit a fatal error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it should be like this

```
$popup_array = array();
foreach($xml->config->popup as $popup_item)
{
    $duplicate_test = (string) $popup_item->attributes()->name; 
    if (!in_array($duplicate_test, $popup_array)){
        $popup_array[] = $duplicate_test;
    }
    else {
        echo "match found for " . $duplicate_test;
    }
}
```

You should check `if not in array` and then `push/add` it inside `$popup_array`, no need to use `$i` as an index for the array. Also check [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Answer (score 0):

use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-diff.php)

```
$arr = array(1=>'word',2=>'otherword',3 =>'Hello' ,4=>'hello', 5=>'KKKKK');

//Case Sensitive
$withoutDuplicates = array_unique(array_map("strtoupper", $arr));
$duplicates = array_diff($arr, $withoutDuplicates);
print_r($duplicates);
```

will print :

```
Array
(
[3] => Hello
[4] => hello
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This value returns an object, not a string:

```
$popup_item->attributes()->name
```

So, the objects probably differ by some XML attribute other than name. Try casting to a string, so that your array index is just the name:

```
$duplicate_test = (string) $popup_item->attributes()->name;
```